# How to Export discord server bans into a txt file discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

im trying to make a savebans command to export all the banned users into a txt file
what ive tried is

```py
@Eagle.command()
async def savebans(ctx):
  exporting = open("bans.txt","w")
  banz = []
  for bans in await ctx.guild.bans():
    banz.append(bans)    
  for ban in banz:
    exporting.write(ban)
    exporting.close()
```

Im sorry if this is a stupid question i am new to discord.py and python i switched from C Coding so thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look something like this:

```
@Eagle.command()
async def savebans(ctx):
  banz = []
  for bans in await ctx.guild.bans():
    banz.append(bans)   
  with open("bans.txt", "a") as exporting:
    for ban in banz:
      exporting.write(ban)
```

You can also use the open("bans.txt","w") but this will overwrite the files contents. Choose whatever fits your usecase best :)

Apart from that opening the file with this syntax:

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as file:
  file.write(content)
```

Will close the file properly if an error occurs. Your approach will not to that if an error occurs before exporting.close() is called.
This is also the reason why I moved the bans fetch outside the file write block.

For further information see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp)

Comment: Note also that the original post was closing the file in each iteration of the second for loop. May I also suggest you add an example using list comprehension for the `banz` list?

Answer (score -2):

This should work

```
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason = None):
    await ctx.member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.author.send(f"You have been banned from {guild} for {reason}")
    # saving the ban
    print(f"Banned {member} for {reason}", open=file("banlogs.txt", "a"))
```

I'm not sure if it'll work